# Problems making Symfony 1.4 work in local

Tags: symfony-1.4, wamp

I am currently an intern in a company that has a website under **Symfony 1.4** and I am having troubles making it work locally, using **wamp**.

When I go to `127.0.0.1/website/web`, I get the following errors:

```
Warning: require_once(C:\wamp\www\website\config/../../lib/symfony-1.4/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php): 
  failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\website\config\ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\website\config/../../lib/symfony-1.4/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php' (include_path='.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear') in C:\wamp\www\website\config\ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 3
```

Even though I copied all the files from the server, I can't seem to find any `symfony-1.4` folder in my `www` folder.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is that it can't file the `sfCoreAutoload.class.php` with the path specified in your `ProjectConfiguration.class.php`. You need to open your `\config\ProjectConfiguration.class.php` and change the path so that it's correct. It's looking for it here:

`C:\wamp\www\website\config/../../lib/symfony-1.4/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php`

When it's probably in this location:

`C:\wamp\www\website\config/../lib/symfony-1.4/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php`

So change the first line in your `ProjectConfiguration.class.php` to something like this:

`require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';`

Answer (score 2):

You need to [install symfony](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/03-Running-Symfony#chapter_03_sub_installing_symfony).

- [Download symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/get/symfony-1.4.20.zip)
- Create a folder `symfony-1.4` inside `/lib`
- unzip the archive inside this folder
- go to `C:\wamp\www\website` in your console and run this command to be sure every thing is ok

  ```
  php lib/symfony-1.4/data/bin/symfony -V
  ```